# Non uniqueness of solution to system of polynomial equations using Gröbner bases

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, groebner-basis

Consider the system of polynomial equations
\begin{align}
x + y + z &= a,\\
xy &= b,\\
z&=c,
\end{align}
where $x, y, z$ are the unknowns, and $a,b,c$ are known real numbers. It is clear at a first glance that there exist at least two solutions to the system: the variables $x$ and $y$ can be exchanged.

I don't understand how I can use Gröbner bases to decide (in a more general case) on whether a system of polynomial equations may have multiple solutions. The Gröbner basis for the system above is $\{z-c,y^2+(c-a)y+b,x+y+c-a\}$ (computed with Mathematica). How would I use the Gröbner basis to conclude?

(Example taken from [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.03960))

Comment: You are right about the second part, the first not really because it does not have a unique solution, does it?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have modified the question according to your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Note that Groebner bases depend on a choice of monomial order (so one wouldn't say THE Groebner basis without specifying an order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Groebner basis is given by
$$
\mathcal{G}=\{ xy - b,a - x - y - z,c - z\},
$$
and the solutions in $\Bbb C(a,b,c)$ are given by
$$
(x,y,z)=(x,a-c-x,c),
$$
where $x$ is one of the two roots of
$$
x^2+(a+c)x+b=0.
$$
This follows directly from the equations.